# Download a directory from a blob URI using MSBuild

Tags: github, download, msbuild, uri

*I am not positive that I am asking this question with the correct vocabulary, so I will try to give as much context as possible.*

My goal is to download a directory from Github using MSBuild.

After searching, it does not appear that there is any easy inbuilt way to do this.  Downloading individual files is easy, but entire directories is difficult.

---

My current attempt involves using an external tool: [DownGit](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home).  This tool generates download links from GitHub. However, trying to use the `DownloadFile` MSBuild task does not give the expected results: it downloads the HTML of the webpage itself instead of getting the zip from the download link.

After further investigation, it looks like the actual download link itself is different from the initial link.

*(Warning: link will download a zip if used.)*
Initial Link: `https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/AzeTheGreat/ONI-Mods/tree/master/src/oniModTemplate`
Download Link: `blob:https://minhaskamal.github.io/08c94867-01c0-489c-b8b9-1f80221cf583`

**How can I go from the initial link** (which is human readable and allows me to dynamically modify it as needed in MSBuild), **to the actual download link** (which will give me the directory I need, but appears to be unique each time)?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you considered just skipping using 3rd party tools except git itself, by cloning (with `--depth 1` for speed) to a temporary directory and copy the needed directory? Should always work, also for other hosting (gitlab, local repositories, ...), no need to unzip.

Comment: @stijn: Sure, but I really dislike that solution.  This is a build action so speed is somewhat important.  Downloading an order of magnitude more data every time is a hard pill to swallow.

Comment: If speed is important, not downloading everything needed will probably be the fastest option except the first time. I.e. get a local clone once, then pull on each build. Unless for CI builds except when they have the option to persist state in between builds.